# Element with scaleX(-1) disappears during translateY animation on Mobile only

Tags: css, mobile, transform, element

I have a quasi-workaround by using flipped images instead of flipping them dynamically. The occurrence is greatly reduced by still happens in a narrow band on the right hand side now.

> **I give up. The workaround will have to due for the now.**

Using `scaleX(-i)` on the elements that disappear seems to be part of the issue. Not sure what the solution is, but this is more progress.

I have a webpage that works flawlessly on desktop as well as in desktop DEV MODE mobile device emulation.

But, at least on all of the iPhones I've tested, the animations of intermittent elements added to the page dynamically disappear during the animation, but reappear when the transition is done. NOTE: this only happens to objects that involve an image (either a background-image, or are img tags themselves). If there is an image involved, the entire element disappears during transform.

The problem occurs when I add a random multiplier to the scaleX:

```
let randY = 1;
let randX = randY * Number(getRandomInt(0, 2) < 1 ? -1 : 1);
bug.style.transform = 'translate(' + Number(tempX - 20) + 'px, ' + Number(tempY - 20) + 'px) scaleX(' + randX + ') scaleY(' + randY + ')';
```

[Test app](http://wilvoss.com/bugst)

I'm changing the transform of the newly created elements dynamically with javascript.

*Interestingly, I've discovered that adding elements on the far left of the mobile screen works perfectly (at least so far). This is progress.*

Comment: I don’t think this is the root of your problem, but I think perspective needs units. It’s possible different browsers treat this in different ways.

Comment: I will try that too, thanks :) No dice. :(